# How to add and Remove Rows from rdlc Report

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

In my Project I am using RDLC reporting,
I have Number of Rows of tools in it, which values fill by my combo box,
Every time i am passing 2 or 3 rows value, other values is Null,
So, I am looking for Code, by which i can Add or Remove Rows dynamically from RDLC Report.

Note: Its vb.net Desktop application

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove blank Space in rdlc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109121/how-to-remove-blank-space-in-rdlc)

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions to your problem.

If your Table is connected to a Dataset you can populate it only with Non-Null values.

If you don't use DataSet and your Table has 3 fixed rows, you can use Hidden property to hide TableRow with Null values.

Comment: I am using My Property Class File as a data source, I am looking for command when i am getting value from class file "" that row hide from report ,
I am using this command, 
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!SetBarcode.Value),False,True)
Its hide column but it leave blank space between upper and below row, i also want to remoce it

Comment: This is an Hide property so you must use: =IIf(IsNothing(Fields!SetBarcode.Value), True, False)

Comment: I want to hide row, if any one of these fields is empty, it should not show the blank space,
its hide successfully but Create Blank space, Which I want to Remove.

Comment: Have you tried =IIf(IsNothing(Fields!SetBarcode.Value), True, False)? This is different from what you said in your first comment.