# How to remove blank Space in rdlc

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I am working with Rdlc report. I have these fields:

```
First name :       fn_data  

Address1  :         add1_Data

Address2  :        add2_data

City, state, zip : city_data
```

If any one of these fields is empty, it should not show the blank space. For example (expected output)

First name,
Address1,
City, state, zip
But, as show in the above image, I am getting this:

```
First name,  
Address1,  
........................<-(blankspace is showing here)  
City, state, zip
```

I tried changing Visiblity -> Expression -> ==IIF(IsNothing(Fields!add2_data.Value),False,True)
How can I remove this Blanck Space??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visibility.Hidden property you have to specify if the object must be hide or not.
So you can use:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!YourData.Value), True, False)
```

If you're using Table/Tablix you have to set Visibility property of your TABLEROW.

Comment: may be u r not getting what i want,
If any one of these fields is empty, it should not shown, it should hide. for example, as per my question, address2 completely hide n city field should appear just below address1

Comment: what VB.NET are you using? In VB.NET 2005, 2008 and 2010 in the Visibility property group you have to set the Hidden property, so you have to specify if the object must be hide or not. So what you are telling in your code is: IIF(IsNothing(Fields!add2_data.Value), SHOW IT!, HIDE IT!). The code in my answer could be translated as: IIF(IsNothing(Fields!add2_data.Value), HIDE IT!, SHOW IT!). Maybe the problem is another: i.e. YourData is not Nothing but simply a Space(0).

Comment: Problem is not about Show and hide, data my data is hide sucessfully,
bt problem is i want to change location of next row,
I mean if address2 has null value, and i am hiding it, so, city row  should move on step upward in place of address2.

Comment: Are you using a Table (2005/2008)? A Tablix (2012)? A simple TextBox? In the first 2 cases you have to set Visibility property of your TABLEROW, not of the SINGLE cell. In the third case you have to set Visibility and CanShrink property.

Comment: @tezzo.. I got it.
actually I am setting individual visibility property,
i mean for m setting Address2 and add2_data instead of set entire Row property,
when i set this property to the entire row, below row automatically shift upward.. Thank you for your help

Comment: =IIF((Fields!setproductname.Value = ""), True, False) ...This is the Final Answer