# hiding a textbox if text value is null

Tags: rdlc

I have done a research on this but can't seem to find a convincing answer. Here is the scenario. I am doing a reporting application in rdlc. I am getting field values from my database and displaying in the text boxes. Please see below what I display in the report

Textbox1
   Textbox2
   Textbox3

In case the value of text box 2 or any other text box is null, I don't display the same using the formular 
    iif(fields!Textbox2.value is nothing, false, true)
for example this is what I get

Textbox1

Textbox3

with a space between textbox1 and textbox3. I dont want this space to appear incase the value is null. How can I handle this? Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove blank Space in rdlc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109121/how-to-remove-blank-space-in-rdlc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a simple TextBox you have to set Visibility and CanShrink property.

If you're using a TextBox in a Table/Tablix you have to set Visibility property of the entire TableRow containing the TextBox.